# F# string formatting - using the same value twice

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I am trying to find the F# equivalent of the following C# snippet

```
string.Format("A: {0} B: {1} A again: {0} C: {2}", a, b, c);
```

I can do this with:

```
sprintf "A: %s B: %s A again: %s C: %s" a b a c
```

However, I am wondering if there is any way to reference the a property twice like in the C# example.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating multiple printf format placeholders with same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055803/populating-multiple-printf-format-placeholders-with-same-value)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fortunately `String.Format` still works in F#.

```
> open System;;
> String.Format("Hello {0} {0}", "world");;
val it : string = "Hello world world"
```

Comment: String.Format is not type safe and until now (2020-11) it caused segfaults in cases when there was a mismatch between the first and second parameters.